# Did not find acceptable output video pin in the given source

Tags: c#, directshow, aforge

I'm using AForge Video Source Player to playback a couple movie clips that exist in my local filesystem within a winforms application.

Example of my playback code:

```
videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = new AForge.Video.AsyncVideoSource(new FileVideoSource(fileName), true);
videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource.VideoSourceError += VideoSource_VideoSourceError;
videoSourcePlayer.Start();
```

I found it odd it didn't showed any videos on production machines although it worked on my development machine. I went ahead and found this among the error logs.

This was outputted from the event `VideoSourceError`.

```
Did not find acceptable output video pin in the given source
```

Can someone tell me how do I solve this ?

Thank you.

---

**Answer:** Thanks to [valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2261657/valter)

Maybe you are missing a [video filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28video%29) for your particular video file. Try installing a filter/codec package.

Comment: Maybe a filter is missed.

Comment: @valter Good idea. Didn't occurred to me. Let me install a filter package and check it again.

Comment: @valter You were right. Submit it as a answer and I will accept it for future reference within SO. Thank you.

Comment: No need. Glad to see your problem is fixed. Thank you though.

Comment: which package did you install? I installed all of Aforge, didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi This question was a long time ago. But I remember that after installing a utility like `K Lite Mega`, which is basically a bundle of encoders and decoders, I no longer experienced this particular problem (in my case).

Comment: @FábioAntunes, did you install it or added packages to visual studio? https://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_basic.htm

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi I installed it from https://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm

Comment: @FábioAntunes, Thank you. It solved my problem. I had to enable relevant packages/codecs in K-Lite.